# How to Switch the Colors in my Logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

Total newbie needing help so that the background is maroon and logo in white...thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu8aa.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the logo has been built, but this should work...

1. Use the direct selection arrow to select any of the maroon elements
2. Go to Select > same file colour from the menu bar
3. Change all of the selected items to a different colour (doesn't matter what colour, it's temporary, but I'm going to say Yellow)
4. Use the direct selection arrow again to select any of the white elements
5. Select same fill colour again
6. Change all of the selected (white) elements to maroon
7. Repeat steps 1-3 to select the bits that were maroon, but are now yellow (or whatever) and change them to white

You might have to do some cleanup and/or add a maroon circle behind the logo to back up the white elements, but this should get you close to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: Select all the white color and change it gray(for example). Select the whole object and go to: Edit>>edit color>>recolor artwork. Grab the small rectangle and move it to the other small rectangle, this will swap the colors. Click the gray color and change it back to white and hit OK. Bye.

[image]